# How to extract zip file when I unzip in R

Tags: r, macos, swirl

I am trying to unzip a file that is in my downloads, I loaded the swirl library and need to follow this step:

`install_course_zip("YOUR_PATH/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi=FALSE)`
Where YOUR_PATH is the folder path where you saved the zip file you downloaded in step 1. This usually looks something like this:

 Mac: /Users/johndoe/Desktop

for reference my file location is Mac:/Users/mgottsch/Downloads and the attempt I've made is as follows:

```r
install_course_zip("Mac:/Users/mgottsch/Downloads/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi= FALSE)
```

I keep getting this error message:

```r
Warning message:
In unzip(path, exdir = swirl_courses_dir()) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

Does anyone know where I am going off course? I've tried moving the zip file to my desktop but it does not seem to make a difference. Thanks!

Comment: remove `Mac:`, as in `install_course_zip("/Users/mgottsch/Downloads/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip",multi= FALSE)`.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem in your file path. It should be OK to write only:

```
install_course_zip("/Users/mgottsch/Downloads/14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip", multi = FALSE)
```

Or place the file inside your working directory (in your case probably `/Users/mgottsch/Documents/`, check it with `getwd()` in your R console) and then load the course via:

```
install_course_zip(file.path(getwd(), "14_740x_Intro_to_R.zip"), multi = FALSE)
```

The [`getwd()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/getwd.html) gets a path to your working directory and [`file.path()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/file.path.html) function makes a complete path to that file in a platform-independent way.